# Google Sheets API write into cell without user seing Auth screen

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a website and I want to present some data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet. And I want the user to be able to modify this data, but without login required.

Is there any way to allow this without having to show them the Google login? I want to use my account to auth this edits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done by embedding a spreadsheet from your google drive.

1. Create a Spreadsheet in Google Drive.
2. Share it with those you want to be able to access it (add entire www).
3. Make sure the other users can **edit**.
4. Adjust width and height property according to your need.

Insert the following code on your site:

```
<iframe width='xxx' height='xxx' frameborder='0' src='THE URL OF YOUR 
SPREADHSEET AS IT SHOWS ON THE WEB BROWSER WHEN YOU SEE IT FROM GOOGLE DRIVE'> 
</iframe>
```

Publish your post/page, and that's it.

Follow the instructions given on these links

1. http://www.cad-addict.com/2013/04/embedding-editable-google-drive-docs.html
2. https://support.google.com/docs/thread/26779507?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google sheets API.

1- Make a request to the API using an authorized client to serve the data you want collected from your sheet in your HTML website.

2- Make another request when your visitor submits a form to change the value.

An alternative would be to deploy an Apps script as a webapp embedded in your site, and use the Spreadsheet service to connect to your spreadsheet.

Using a `doGet()` method to serve the initial data from the sheet, and a `doPost()` method to change the value.

---

**References:**

- [Apps script Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [Spreadsheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)